# File 'processor' that moves files automatically based on parameters

Tags: c#, file, filesystemwatcher

I'm in the early **EARLY** stages of creating a program that will, quite simply, route files to their correct destination the second they are dropped.

I have been looking up information, but I would like some concrete suggestions of how to handle this the best and fastest way.

This is what needs to happen: Let's say a file gets dropped in folder A. Based on either the folder or the file, the following needs to happen:

- Log the file (including the blob) in a database, this will always happen.
- Move the file to the correct destination, this could be either a folder linked to the original folder (if there is no **enveloppe** provided on the file, or to a folder based on the **enveloppe** encapsulated around the file.

**What would be the best course of action to make this all run smoothly?**

I've been toying around with the **FileSystemWatcher** class for a while, but I can't provide a destination folder as a parameter for the FileSystemEvenHandler for example, but this is probably an easy solution I'm overlooking. This has been the subject I've been looking up a lot on, but I think I still have to make the 'click'...

**Encapsulating a file:** does it work for literally any file? Let's say I want to encapsulate a PDF because it has to be sent to somewhere else, will the file 'break'? It's probably the best to just put the entire PDF as Base64 in an XML file so I can have smooth communication, right?

Any suggestions are welcome. I know this isn't really a distinct question but anything to get me going would help greatly.

Comment: The filesystemwatcher will watch any file - you can then use your own logic to decide if you want to do something with it or not

Comment: You can (and need to) configure the FileSystemWatcher to watch only a certain directory.

Comment: You need to explicitly and carefully define **EXACTLY** what you mean by "the second they are dropped".  How do you know the entire file is there?  How do you know that there wasn't an error in "dropping" the file?  The only actor that knows that is the file *sender*.  All you can do if you're watching for file system changes is *guess*, unless the sender sends information that the file is complete and correct.